# How get digits after the decimal points in NumberFormat?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, locale, currency, number-formatting

Looking for solution to get full currency value including pennies. `numberingSystem: 'fullwide'` coming with letter spacing when getting full digits. Is there any option to get full digit with currency code in NumberFormat() ?

Expected behaviour: `€56.123456`

```js
const CurrencyFormat = (amount = 0, currency = 'eur', digitLength = 'latn') => {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    numberingSystem: digitLength,
  }).format(amount)
};

console.log(CurrencyFormat(56.123456, 'eur', 'fullwide'));
console.log(CurrencyFormat(56.123456));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `maximumFractionDigits` property to the options with the number of fractional digits you want to permit.

```js
const CurrencyFormat = (amount = 0, currency = 'eur', digitLength = 'latn') => {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    numberingSystem: digitLength,
    maximumFractionDigits: 20,
  }).format(amount)
};

console.log(CurrencyFormat(56.123456, 'eur', 'fullwide'));
console.log(CurrencyFormat(56.123456));
```

I found this by finding the word `MaximumFractionDigits` [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-properties-of-intl-numberformat-instances) and discovering that it's a property on instances which [can be set through the options object.](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-setnfdigitoptions).

Answer (score 1):

`maximumFractionDigits` helped to get decimal

```js
const CurrencyFormat = (amount = 0, currency = 'eur') => {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    maximumFractionDigits: amount.toString().length,
  }).format(amount)
};

console.log(CurrencyFormat(56.123456, 'eur', 'fullwide'));
console.log(CurrencyFormat(56.123456));
```